# Audience targeting not supporting dynamic groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, groups, audience-targeting, audiences

After some tips regarding audience targeting, it seems to be the thing to go with. I want to audience target Buttons, menus, news posts etc... BUT, and there is a big BUT! The audience target functionality does not support dynamic groups? How am I supposed to have some automatic functionality without using dynamic groups? The company is a pretty big one, 2500+ empoyees.

How do you solve this problem?